# Facebook connect - integration into iOS application error

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode4, fbconnect

I am currently trying to integrate Facebook into my iOS application using Xcode. I am trying to follow the Facebook tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/
yet when i try to add the Facebook class i receive an error. I have successfully added the fbconnect folder to my application as well as the src directory to my header search paths in Build Settings. I have just begun the tutorial and am already getting an error. Please Help

this is the code where i received the problem...
    //AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,FBRequestDelegate,FBSessionDelegate,FBDialogDelegate>{

Facebook *fb; //This is where the error is

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property(nonatomic,retain)Facebook *fb;   //This is where the error is
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this line to the top of your code?

"`#import "Facebook.h`"

Comment: The class is now recognized but the Facebook.h File is not found.